# Facebook "feed" dialog Display Issue

Tags: android, iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am Trying to post on facebook with the help of "feed" dialog. I supply some information in post like "link","picture","caption","description","title" etc.

But when i share the post the preview look like the image below:

[image]

My Concern is this I want to show description right align to the dialog after the Image ends. Can i do this by some change in my code.

The updated Screen looks something Like the Image Below:

[image]

```
mFacebook.dialog(MyActivity.this, "feed",parameters, new FbDialogListener());
```

Where parameter is the object of Bundle contains all the values to be posted on Facebook.

There is the same issue with Iphone SDK too.

Comment: Can you clarify what your issue is?  I don't fully understand the problem here.

Comment: my problem is with the post preview. I want the description test must align to right of window as updated screen shot(Edited Manually).

Comment: The description text will _not_ be left aligned (I guess you meant left, not right?) when the post shows up on the user’s timeline – so why should the _preview_ (which is supposed to show the user what the post will look like in the end) behave differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this, the dialogs are rendered from Facebook's side, as is the content itself once posted. You also appear to have attempted to embed HTML in the description, this will also not work as Facebook will not render client-supplied HTML in their interface.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use Facebook's dialog, you can create your own views (e.g. UIView in iOS or View in Android) similar to the second dialog (or whatever you like). On share button tap you can use Facebook's graph API to share it on your wall.

iOS example

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[appDelegate.facebook accessToken],@"access_token",
                                    <your FB app id>, @"api_key",
                                    <message you want to post>, @"message",
                                    imageData, @"source",
                                    nil];
    [appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                          andParams:params 
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
                        andDelegate:appDelegate];
```

See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for graph API.

I am using a similar approach in my iOS app. I designed the share dialog almost similar to Facebook's share UI.